# protobuf-net v2 type meta

Tags: network-protocols, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

According to [this](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/03/objects-graphs-and-all-that-jazz.html) post (from March), protobuf v2 allows us to resolve types from a stream. Since v2 is now in beta 5, I think this feature has already been implemented, so I was wondering how to use this new feature. I haven't been able to find any documentation on it, so some help would be greatly appreciated !

> #### Type meta
>
> > > The serialization is fine, but I don’t know (and cannot know) all of
> > >       my types up front. How can I do this?
>
> Well, protobuf is a contract based format; if you don’t know the
>   types, it will struggle – as will any contract based serializer…
>
> > > Yes, I get that; now: how do I do it?
>
> Now, I’ve held off putting any meta in the stream for various reasons:
>
> it steps far outside the core protobuf spec it flashes the warning
>   signs of BinaryFormatter, my nemesis But, so many people seem to want
>   this that I think I have to buckle; but on my terms! So in v2, I’m
>   adding the ability to indicate that (on a per-member basis) objects
>   should resolve their type information from the stream. By default, by
>   embedding the assembly-qualified-name, but providing an abstraction
>   layer over that allowing you to provide your own string<===>Type map
>   (and thus avoiding the knots in by stomach caused by too much type
>   dependency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use the `DynamicType = true` option on a member *to* your object - as an over-simplified example:

```
[ProtoMember(12, DynamicType = true)]
public object CouldBeAnything {get;set;}
```

Re the "string<===>Type map", that is the `DynamicTypeFormatting` event on `TypeModel`. If you are using the `Serializer.*` methods, that is a shortcut (mainly for preserving the v1 API) to the `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` serializer instance.

(as a side-note, in writing this I did notice an edge-case that I need to go and fix in the code)

Note: another approach here, rather than using `DynamicType`, is to simply *configure the model at runtime*, for example:

```
var knownTypes = GetMyKnownTypesAtRuntimeWithUniqueIdentifiers();
var metaType = typeModel[typeof(MyBaseClass)];
foreach(var knownType in knownTypes)
{
    metaType.AddSubType(knownType.UniqueIdentifier, knownType.Type);
}
```

IMO this latter is my *preferred* option, and will generally be more efficient. Note that it is necessary for the unique-identifiers to be fixed/repeatable, as that is part of the wire format (don't just use the index of the order you find them).

Comment: This is the only place I've been able to find that explains how to configure the model at runtime. Thank you, Marc.

Comment: @MarcGravell Does the DynamicType's meta data compatible with protobuf's DymanicMessage.

Comment: @Logan no; different concept, with an annoyingly similar naming choice