# Protobuf-net auto-generating field numbers for subtypes

Tags: protobuf-net

I saw this question [Subtype fieldnumber order dependent in protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332380/subtype-fieldnumber-order-dependent-in-protobuf-net) and am wondering whether there is a way now to automatically generate a unique and deterministic field number for each subtype? The reason that using `ProtoInclude` is not desirable for me is that I don't want to have to manually add a `ProtoInclude` line every time I define a new subtype. The reason I need it to be deterministic is that I have two executables and message is sent between them. So they need to use the same field number, otherwise the type will be incorrect after deserialization.

Comment: The many problems with reliably and repeatably generating such a number is *why* it needs to be done explicitly. You can set it in code if you don't want to add attributes, but it needs to come from somewhere, and work even if you add/remove/rename/relocate types.

Comment: I see..thanks for the feedback. I am thinking of using the result from GetHashCode() of the type as the FieldNumber. What would be the issue with that approach?

Comment: Do not do that! `GetHashCode()` is a: not guaranteed to be unique, but more importantly b: doesn't have to be the same value between different runs of the same executable, let alone between build / framework versions / etc. IIRC ServiceStack (which uses the lib) does something involving a reliable repeatable hash of the namespace (but not assembly) qualified type name. That might work for you?

Comment: I will try that. Thanks a lot for the advice!