# protobuf-net - Not specify sub types of a base class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have an inheritance chain such as this:

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class Message
{
    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
    public List<Header> Headers {get; set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class EventMessage<T> : Message
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public T Event {get; set;}
}
```

The inheritance chain is very straight forward (my . In order to get the Headers to be included in the serialization, I need to do:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Packet)].AddSubType(3, typeof(Message<PayloadType>));
```

I know this sort of answer (the line above) has been documented on quite a few StackOverflow posts. However, I don't like this design because then I need to declare all my subtypes ahead of time and it's also implying a limited, small number of subtypes.

I'm attempting to code a message bus in my application, using protobuf-net for the serialization/deserialization. The message bus needs to send out 'events' and respond to request/replies. Since I have many (easily > 100) events in my system, I don't want to declare a subtype for every closed generic type in the RuntimeTypeModel.

Does protobuf-net have the ability to infer subtypes/classes? Or ideally, I'd like something like:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Packet)].AddSubType(3, typeof(Message<>));
```

(Which I tried and it doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the protobuf wire format, the only identifiers sent are the numeric keys (like the 1,2,3 in your example). After that data has been serialized, you will presumably want it to deserialize in the future - and doing that reliably if the keys are not explicitly specified is *hugely* problematic. Especially since those sub-types could be declared in different assemblies, so it can't even infer them by reflection.

At the moment, the short answer is "they must be specified". Note that I didn't say "in attributes" - the subtypes can also be specified via the `RuntimeTypeModel` API at runtime, if that is more convenient.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the rapid feedback. Although it's not the answer I was hoping for, I understand that the type isn't included on the wire format. To solve my problem, I think I'll just do some of auto registration: scan the loaded assemblies in the current AppDomain for all types that inherit from my base class, etc. For the keys, I can always use the hash code on the System.Type.Name. Similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702172/protobuf-net-v2-type-meta.

Comment: @pdalbe01 just make sure you can guarantee getting the same keys for each type... this is important. Reflection rarely makes any guarantees about the order things will be discovered. The "obvious" choice of "alphabetical" is tricky as people add / remove / rename classes, so it is quite important to think about how you will reliably associate a key number with each type. An attribute *on the derived type* might do the job.