# Protobuf-net List of DynamicType error

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I see that I can serialize interfaces derived classes without specifying upfront by setting DynamicType=true, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702172/protobuf-net-v2-type-meta).

However I'm trying to serialize a Dictionary whose values are a List of the interface, like this:

```
[ProtoMember(35, DynamicType=true)]
public Dictionary<int, List<iAnInterface>> vals;
```

and I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve a suitable Add method for System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[myFuncs.iFilter, myFuncs20, Version=1.0.5367.32298, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>      at ProtoBuf.Serializers.ListDecorator..ctor(TypeModel model, Type declaredType, Type concreteType, IProtoSerializer tail, Int32 fieldNumber, Boolean writePacked, WireType packedWireType, Boolean returnList, Boolean overwriteList, Boolean supportNull) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\ListDecorator.cs:line 85
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.BuildSerializer() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\ValueMember.cs:line 348
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.get_Serializer() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\ValueMember.cs:line 191
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 465
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 381
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 692
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object value) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 186
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 217
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 201
>      at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 87

Is what I am trying to do possible?

EDIT: If I try to do a List (ie, no Dictionary around it), it works.

Comment: Can you add the rest of error message?

Comment: added rest of error message